# Filter in input only integer with dot and one place after dot

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the code below. It's working well, but I have small problem with places after a dot. I can add many integers after a dot. I need to limit to only one integer after a dot. How can I co that?

```
function validateNumber() {
  var clean = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "").replace(/(,.*?),(.*,)?/, "$1");
  if (clean !== this.value) 
    this.value = clean;
}

document.querySelector('.number-mask').oninput = validateNumber;
```

Answer (score 2):

To only allow one integer after the comma value you need to amend your regex. The first replace needs to change the `.` to `,` to allow a comma to be entered. In the second regex you need to change it to retain only the first value after the comma, which can be done using a capturing group. Try this:

```js
function validateNumber() {
  var clean = this.value.replace(/[^0-9,]/g, "").replace(/(,\d)\d+?/, "$1");
  if (clean !== this.value) 
    this.value = clean;
}

document.querySelector('.number-mask').addEventListener('input', validateNumber);
```

```html
<input type="text" class="number-mask" />
```

Also note the preferred use of `addEventListener()` over `onX` properties.

> Sorry, I wrong translate. I need dots. I need integer . integer one place after dot

In that case you don't need to amend the first regex:

```js
function validateNumber() {
  var clean = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "").replace(/(\.)\.{2,}/g, "$1").replace(/(.\d)\d+?/, "$1");
  if (clean !== this.value) 
    this.value = clean;
}

document.querySelector('.number-mask').addEventListener('input', validateNumber);
```

```html
<input type="text" class="number-mask" />
```

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I wrong translate. I need dots. I need integer . integer one place after dot

Comment: And disable option to write something like this: 1..... (one integer and many dots)

Comment: Thank you. In your current code, I can only enter two numbers and a period + one number after the point. Is it possible to increase the digit limit to 5?

Comment: I updated the answer for you. To change the regex to accept 5dp change `(.\d)` in the last regex to `(.\d){5,}`

Comment: Doesn't work very well :(
I have 3 inputs on the page with class number-mask '

1. Instead of numbers I can write: .. (double dots - no numbers)
2.I can only type XX.X (two integer coma one integer)

I have the code: document.querySelector ('. Number-mask1'). AddEventListener ('input', validateNumber);

document.querySelector ('. number-mask2'). addEventListener ('input', validateNumber);

document.querySelector ('. number-mask3'). addEventListener ('input', validateNumber);

Comment: 1. I updated again after you noted that in the comment. 2. It would have helped if you'd given an accurate description in the question. Your last update was `I need integer . integer one place after dot`

Comment: Ok. On the website I have 3 inputs with the number-mask class.

I would like to:
You can enter up to 5 numbers + period + one number after the point (mask: #####. #)

Right now I have this code:
https://pastebin.com/X1ZGQdm0

Problem:
1. I can enter instead of numbers: .. (two dots)
2. After the dot, I can enter 5 numbers (and the limit is 1)

Comment: yes, I need integer . integer one place after dot - #####. #. Now can I write #.####, ##.## or .. :) are you understand me? :)